# Style in ngFor loop

Tags: angular

I have an app which I'm developing in Angular 2 (RC1). The menu is need to be created from the database. Data is delivered via Web Api in JSON form. I would like to build menu from the data recursively, to be sure that depth of the menu is not an issue.

The problem is when I'm want to add class on particular row of ngFor loop, and the class is added to all rows instead of just one I want to.

The code is looking something like this:

**sidenav.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { IMenu } from '../../../shared/models/menu.interface';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu.component';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'sidenav',
    templateUrl: 'sidenav.component.html',
    directives: [MenuComponent]
})
export class SidenavComponent {
    @Input() menu: IMeni[]
}
```

**sidenav.component.html**

```
...
<menu-view [menu]="menu"></menu-view>
...
```

**menu.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { IMenu } from '../../../shared/models/menu.interface';
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'menu-view',
    templateUrl: 'menu.component.html',
    directives: [MenuComponent]
})
export class MenuComponent {
    isSelected: boolean = false;
    @Input() meni: IMeni[];

    onSelect(): void {
        this.isSelected = !this.isSelected;
    }
}
```

**menu.component.html**

```
<ul>
     <li  *ngFor="let item of menu; let frst=first"
           class="menu-list" 
           [ngClass]="{'active': 'isSelected', 'active': 'frst'}">

        <a [routerLink]="[item.uri]" (click)="onSelect()" > {{item.name}}</a>

        <meni-view [menu]="item.children"></meni-view>

     </li>
</ul>
```

So, when I click on parent all parents become active, not only that particular one, what will be satisfying behaviour. What I do wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "click on parent all parents become active"? Should this be "click on parent all `MenuComponent` become active"?

Comment: When menu is built it gives an hierarchy of parent and child items. Let's say that the model for the menu is: ` id: number; parentId: number; name: string; children: IMenu[];`. So, when I click on parent instance of menu item, I open all instances of parent menus. The wanted behavior should be that when I click on parent instance, it will open, or to say give correct class only to block with children of the selected parent.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems like your variable **isSelected** is shared across the list. Change the variable to track the index instead.

```
export class App {
    menu = [{name: "Item 1", url: "/item1"}, {name: "Item 2", url: "/item2"},{name: "Item 3", url: "/item3"}];
    selectedIdx = 0;

    selectItem(index):void {
        this.selectedIdx = index;
    }
}
```

render it with

```
<li  *ngFor="let item of menu;let i = index"
   class="menu-list" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedIdx == i}">
   <a (click)="selectItem(i)"> {{item.name}}</a>
</li>
```

Working 
http://plnkr.co/edit/7aDLNnhS8MQ1mJVfhGRR

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: Works like a charm! Nice answer!

Answer (score 3):

There are some redundant `'`. I guess you want to bind the value of the property `isSelected` not the `'isSelected'` string (same with `frst`)

```
 <li  *ngFor="let item of menu; let frst=first"
       class="menu-list" 
       [ngClass]="{'active': isSelected, 'active': frst}">
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried without `'` with the same result. I keep coding with `'` because it gives me possibility to include other logical questions, like: `[ngClass]="{'nav-stacked': 'item.depth === 1' }" ` .

Comment: That particular syntax (`[ngClass]="{'nav-stacked': item.depth===1}"`) doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, but if you add one more class, it will fail: `[ngClass]="{'nav-stacked': item.depth===1, 'active': item.depth > 1}"`

Comment: Still working fine https://plnkr.co/edit/5t0cxwMHzTe9HFEC2IYJ?p=preview but breaks when I add `'` https://plnkr.co/edit/4MLyt1rb08eJqaIgVYVs?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

I got a solution (and it's easy), when you receive the JSON data and save it in a variable of yours (in your case its called **`menu`**) add to **`menu`** a new field called classes and render it in the template!

Example:

```
@Input() menu: IMenu[]; 
getMenu(){
  this.http.get(url).then(data => {
    this.menu = data;
    for(let i = 0; i < this.menu.length; i++) {
      if(i == indexOfWantedElement){
        this.menu[i].classes = "myClass";
        continue;
      }
      this.menu[i].classes = ""; // others will have no classes 
    }
  }
}
```

and in the template you can render it easliy

```
<ul>
  <li  *ngFor="let item of menu;" class="menu-list {{ item.classes }}">
    <a [routerLink]="[item.uri]" (click)="onSelect()" >{{item.name}}</a>
    <meni-view [menu]="item.children"></meni-view>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try for sure. I will still look for the answer without looping one more time through the array, though.

Comment: @IgorIlić the answer by ***zaclerv*** that you **verified** is great but it's only working on click! my answer will add the class to multiple elements and without the click event, that's the diffrence! anyway good luck fella :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `#clickState` to your row in the `*ngFor`

```
<row #clickState>
     <i class="icon-cloud-download"
        *ngIf="!clickState.clicked"
        (click)="clickState.clicked=true"></i>
     <i class="fa fa-spinner"
         *ngIf="clickState.clicked 
         (click)="clickState.clicked=false"></i>
</row>
```