# Angular 4 - Toggling background color in *ngFor

Tags: angular

I'm a beginner with angular 4.
I need help to set a style with ngStyle.
I need set a style when I clicked on one `<li>`, as I did I change the color to all `<li>`, I need to change color only at `<li>` clicked.

Template:

```
<div  class="div1" id="sp1" align="center" >
  <ul class="r ">
    <li [ngStyle]="verde" *ngFor="let posto of posti" class="s ye" id="{{posto.id}}" title="" value="{{posto.id}}" (click)="myclick($event)"  >
     {{posto.id}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Component:

```
export class PostiComponent {

  posti = [ARRAY OF POSTI];
  verde: object;

  constructor() {   
  }

  myclick(event) {  
    console.log(event);
    this.verde = { 'background-color': 'green' };
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37545947/style-in-ngfor-loop

Comment: it isn't , it's the same contest but i need hel for another problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For toggling items style in a list, do this

**in hello.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  <div  class="div1" id="sp1" align="center" >
  <ul class="r ">
    <li [class.background]="posto.isSelected"  *ngFor="let posto of posti; let i=index" class="s ye" id="{{posto.id}}" title="" value="{{posto.id}}" (click)="myclick(posto)"  >
     {{posto.id}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
`,
  styleUrls: ["./hello.component.css"]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
 posti = [{id:1, isSelected:false}, {id:2, isSelected:false}];

  constructor() {   
  }

  selectedIndex:number = -1;

  myclick(posto:any) {  
    posto.isSelected = !posto.isSelected;
  }
}
```

**in hello.component.css**

```
.background{ background-color:green}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f45mzv for working example

Comment: I don't know how you were handling css before. Can you edit your post with that information ?  you just have to include the rule `.background{ background-color:green}` into your existing css file

Comment: i try to include .background{ background-color:green} in file css but not change color.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f45mzv?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts works perfectly for me. Have you tried it?

Comment: thank you, and  to make the selected article remain? when i click another item the first one remains colored

Comment: I dont understand. Do you want the color to stick or do you want to attach color only to the clicked item ?

Comment: I want the color to remain attached until I shoot it back on itself

Comment: No problem. Next time, make sure that your OP states the expected behaviour correctly . This is called "toggling"

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
<div  class="div1" id="sp1" align="center" >
  <ul class="r " *ngFor="let posto of posti">
    <li [ngStyle]="selectedId === posto.id" class="s ye" id="{{posto.id}}" title="" value="{{posto.id}}" (click)="myclick(posto)"  >
     {{posto.id}} 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

on click of that, your method should be like

```
public selectedId : number;    
myclick(posto){
    this.selectedId = posto.id;
    }
```

Comment: in function this.selectedId not exist

Comment: SelectedId is a local variable in TS